# Power source connected event UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on a UWP application in C#. 
We have a requirement to perform an operation whenever device is connected to power source for charging. We need to sense that event and do our tasks which are dependent on it.

So far I have found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/get-battery-info) which raises event when 1% charging is decreased
but we are interested in device connected to power source event.

I got one example where event is binded when page loads.

```
Battery.AggregateBattery.ReportUpdated += AggregateBattery_ReportUpdated;
```

and get the report as below.

```
private void GetBatteryReport(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Clear UI
            BatteryReportPanel.Children.Clear();


            if (AggregateButton.IsChecked == true)
            {
                // Request aggregate battery report
                RequestAggregateBatteryReport();
            }
            else
            {
                // Request individual battery report
                RequestIndividualBatteryReports();
            }

            // Note request
            reportRequested = true;
        }
```

This is not what I require.

Can anyone please guide me how to sense device power source connected event?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstatus.powerlinestatus.aspx

Comment: @MarkNg.. This is not available in UWP application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the battery status:

```
private void OnPageLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PowerManager.BatteryStatusChanged += OnBatteryStatusChanged;
        }

        private async void OnBatteryStatusChanged(object sender, object e)
        {
            var bs = PowerManager.BatteryStatus;

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                var dischargeTime = PowerManager.RemainingDischargeTime;
                this.batteryProgress.Value = PowerManager.RemainingChargePercent;
                this.batteryProgressPercentage.Text = PowerManager.RemainingChargePercent + " % remaining";
                this.batteryStatus.Text = "Battery Level: " + bs;
                this.batteryDischargeTime.Text = "Battery Left: " + dischargeTime.Hours + " hours " + dischargeTime.Minutes + " minutes " + dischargeTime.Seconds + " seconds";
            });
        }
```

Comment: How can we detect power source connected event? Can you provide more explanation.

Comment: This event is not available in UWP application.

Comment: @Michael.. Suppose we have tablet. When charger is connected with tablet. We need to detect that event.

Comment: @Michael, sorry I did not see the `uwp` tag, see updated code.

Comment: @Michael, did you get it sorted out?

Comment: Whenever I run above mentioned code, it crashes application.

Comment: I am getting 'Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe has stopped working' error

Comment: I am able to fix problem. https://thomas-barthelemy.github.io/2015/05/01/visual-studio-vshub/

Comment: @Michael, glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

PowerManager.PowerSupplyStatus can be Adequate, InAdequate, or NotPresent:

```
        var pss = PowerManager.PowerSupplyStatus;
        if (pss.ToString() == "NotPresent")
        {
                 pluggedin = false;
        } else {
                 pluggedin = true;
        }
```

Comment: There's an event for this changing too, docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power.powermanager